# Oracle to Impala Query Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop, impala

We are migrating from Oracle to Hadoop, I am trying to covert the following query which is written in Oracle sql to Impala sql:

`CASE WHEN UPPER(table1.ACC_NBR) = LOWER(table1.ACC_NBR) THEN
SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,5,1)||'-'||SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,8,2)||'-'||
SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,10,3)||'-'||SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,13,6) 
ELSE
SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,5,1)||'-'||SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,6,2)||'-' ||
SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,10,2)||'-'||SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,13,6) 
END`

I am using this query in Business object Universe Designing tool and it gives me error

> SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR,5,1) or ||'-'|| is a Boolean expected string

. Can someone have a look at the query and see what's missing or extra.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`||` is not recognized as concatenation operator in impala. Use `CONCAT` function instead.

```
CASE
   WHEN
      UPPER(table1.ACC_NBR) = LOWER(table1.ACC_NBR) 
   THEN
      CONCAT ( SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 5, 1), '-', SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 8, 2), '-',
               SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 10, 3), '-', SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 13, 6) ) 
   ELSE
      CONCAT ( SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 5, 1), '-', SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 6, 2), '-' , 
               SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 10, 2), '-', SUBSTR(table1.ACC_NBR, 13, 6) ) 
END
```